# Retrofit 2. Обработка запроса с различной возможной структурой ответа

Tags: json, retrofit2

Подскажите, как лучше обработать запрос с помощью Retrofit 2, если на него может придти ответ разной структуры?
Вот конкретный пример - на POST запрос

```
@POST("Authorization/Login")
Call<Authorization> authorization(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, 
@Body JSONLoginPassword jsonLoginPassword);
```

приходит JSON-ответ c двумя параметрами: `status` и `data`, причем если `"status":"ok"`, то `data` это строка символов (токен, например `"data":"xxx308f9-04xx3a-4xxxd-b6ba-89xx9c8xxxx"`). А если `"status":"error"`, то `data` например может быть таким `"data":{"code":"wrong-login-or-password","message":"Неверный логин или пароль"}`, то есть уже не строка, а набор пар name:value. Соответственно если я задаю одну из структур ответа, а приходит другая, то мой метод `authorization` вываливается в `onFailure` с ошибкой  `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`.
Есть ли в Retrofit 2 инструменты для создания альтернативной структуры ответа, и если нет, то как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, хоть я и много чего делал при помощи этой библиотеки, я не могу вам с уверенностью сказать есть ли механизмы для создания альтернативной структуры ответа. Что я вам могу предложить, у вас с сервера приходит ответ, который вы разбираете если условие `if (response.isSuccessful())` правда. Вам нужно просто создать несколько методов которые будут вызываться в зависимости от того какое значение имеет переменная `status`. Вот например, ваш статус ок, значит вызываем метод для вытаскивания токена, если же статус `error` значит вызываем метод который тянет либо сообщение из ответа, либо сразу не запариваясь выводим какой-то тоаст что у вас проблема.

Это только мое лично мнение, основанное на непродолжительной практике с этой библиотекой, возможно у кого-то будет решения и получше, но я бы делал так. Удачи :)

Comment: Я не могу проверить `status`, если ответ пришел с другой структурой, т.к. вываливаюсь в `onFailure`. В этом-то и проблема.

Comment: Я представляю это примерно так: нужно, чтобы обрабатывалось только поле `status` и в зависимости от его значения для поля `data` применялась та или иная модель, но пока не знаю как реализовать.

Comment: @SergeyGarbuz, да вы совершенно правильно думаете, поведение вашей программы зависит только от переменной `status`. Но я думаю что все таки вам нужно будет так же обрабатывать и приходящее значение `data`. В классе модели вам нужно сделать получение статуса, но дальше вам нужно работать с данными.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый

Answer (score 1):

Сам себя навел на решение вопроса:) `data` сделал типа Object, и потом в `onResponse` в зависимости от значения `status` я либо сразу получаю токен, как `response.body().getData().toString()`, либо преобразую Object в JSONObject и из него методом getString достаю нужные поля.